# How can this code be compacted?

Tags: r

Can the following code be made more "R like"?

Given data.frame inDF:

```
    V1         V2       V3        V4  
1   a          ha       1;2;3     A
2   c          hb       4         B
3   d          hc       5;6       C
4   f          hd       7         D
```

Inside df I want to

1. find all rows which for the "V3" column has multiple values
   separated by ";"
2. then replicate the respective rows a number of times equal with the number of individual values in the "V3" column,
3. and then each replicated row receives in the "V3" column only one the initial values

Shortly, the output data.frame (= outDF) will look like:

```
    V1         V2       V3        V4  
1   a          ha       1         A
1   a          ha       2         A
1   a          ha       3         A
2   c          hb       4         B
3   d          hc       5         C
3   d          hc       6         C
4   f          hd       7         D
```

So, if from inDF I want to get to outDF, I would write the following code:

```
#load inDF from csv file
inDF <- read.csv(file='example.csv', header=FALSE, sep=",", fill=TRUE)  

#search in inDF, on the V3 column, all the cells with multiple values
rowlist <- grep(";", inDF[,3])

# create empty data.frame and add headers from "headDF"
xDF <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=0, ncol=4))
colnames(xDF)=colnames(inDF)

#take every row from the inDF data.frame which has multiple values in col3 and break it in several rows with only one value

for(i in rowlist[])
{ 
  #count the number of individual values in one cell
  value_nr <- str_count(inDF[i,3], ";"); value_nr <- value_nr+1

  # replicate each row a number of times equal with its value number, and transform it to character
  extracted_inDF <- inDF[rep(i, times=value_nr[]),]
  extracted_inDF <- data.frame(lapply(extracted_inDF, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # split the values in V3 cell in individual values, place them in a list
  value_ls <- str_split(inDF[i, 3], ";")

  #initialize f, to use it later to increment both row number and element in the list of values
  f = 1

  # replace the multiple values with individual values
  for(j in extracted_inDF[,3])

    {
    extracted_inDF[f,3] <- value_ls[[1]][as.integer(f)]
    f <- f+1
  }

  #put all the "demultiplied" rows in xDF
  xDF <- merge(extracted_inDF[], xDF[], all=TRUE)
}

# delete the rows with multiple values from the inDF
inDF <- inDF[-rowlist[],]

#create outDF
outDF <- merge(inDF, xDF, all=TRUE)
```

Could you please

Comment: From the Rules of Proper Coding:  Never reinvent the wheel. It wastes time and you're likely to make mistakes, or at the least come up with a nonoptimal solution.

Comment: I agree with not reinventing the wheel. I'm not sure if I know exactly how to use the wheel. Would you have any suggestion of the proper use of R for the example above?

Comment: Look at str_split and strsplit.  In general, base R has some useful string functions, and the `stringr` package has some more.

Comment: I think when starting off, writing your own code is good practice especially since you do not know a lot of the common tools to help with this problem. When I started, it was much faster to write loops and do explicitly what I wanted step-by-step. As you get more familiar with the language and packages, you will do things faster with built-in functions, and your code will be more concise and elegant.

Comment: @rawr Good point, tho' one's "final" solution should be rather different from the initial learning attempts :-)

Comment: thanks guys for your answers. I agree both with not reinventing the wheel and  that, in the beginning, it might be necessary to do so. I've rephrased the question, since I would like to see how an "R like" code would look for the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I'm one to speak about whether you are using R in the "right" or "wrong" way... I mostly just use it to answer questions on Stack Overflow. :-)

However, there are many ways in which your code could be improved. For starters, YES, you should try to become familiar with the predefined functions. They will often be much more efficient, and will make your code much more transparent to other *users of the same language*. Despite your concise description of what you wanted to achieve, and my knowing an answer virtually right away, I found your code daunting to look through.

I would break up your problem into two main pieces: (1) splitting up the data and (2) recombining it with your original dataset.

***For part 1***: You obviously know some of the functions you need--or at least the main one you need: `strsplit`. If you use `strsplit`, you'll see that it returns a `list`, but you need a simple `vector`. How do you get there? Look for `unlist`. The first part of your problem is now solved.

***For part 2***: You first need to determine how many times you need to replicate each row of your original dataset. For this, you drill through your `list` (for example, with `l/s/v-apply`) and count each item's `length`. I picked `sapply` since I knew it would create a vector that I could use with `rep`.

Then, if you've played with `data.frame`s enough, particularly with extracting data, you would have come to realize that `mydf[c(1, 1, 1, 2), ]` will result in a `data.frame` where the first row is repeated two additional times. Knowing this, we can use the `length` calculation we just made to "expand" our original `data.frame`.

Finally, with that expanded `data.frame`, we just need to replace the relevant column with the unlisted values.

---

Here is the above in action. I've named your dataset "mydf":

```
V3 <- strsplit(mydf$V3, ";", fixed=TRUE)
sapply(V3, length)    ## How many times to repeat each row?
# [1] 3 1 2 1
## ^^ Use that along with `[` to "expand" your data.frame
mydf2 <- mydf[rep(seq_along(V3), sapply(V3, length)), ]
mydf2$V3 <- unlist(V3)
mydf2
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1    a ha  1  A
# 1.1  a ha  2  A
# 1.2  a ha  3  A
# 2    c hb  4  B
# 3    d hc  5  C
# 3.1  d hc  6  C
# 4    f hd  7  D
```

---

To share some more options...

The "data.table" package can actually be pretty useful for something like this.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT2 <- DT[, list(new = unlist(strsplit(as.character(V3), ";", fixed = TRUE))), by = V1]
merge(DT, DT2, by = "V1")
```

Alternatively, `concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package pretty much does it in one step, but if you want your exact output, you'll need to drop the `NA` values and reorder the rows.

```
library(splitstackshape)
df2 <- concat.split.multiple(mydf, split.cols="V3", seps=";", direction="long")
df2 <- df2[complete.cases(df2), ]   ## Optional, perhaps
df2[order(df2$V1), ]                ## Optional, perhaps
```

Comment: I've gone through your code and I'm starting to understand what's R about (during my short experience in R I kept writing "for" loops and somehow it did not feel like R; it felt like I could've done in any other programing language and that's when I realized I'm doing something wrong, because R is supposed to have many ready made functions). And for the link with the benchmarking - I was wondering how to measure CPU usage in R. Any suggestion for a package which measures the RAM usage?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use the split-apply-combine paradigm for reshaping the data.

You want to split `inDF` by its rows, since you want to operate on each row separately. I've used the `split` function here to split it up by row:

```
spl = split(inDF, 1:nrow(inDF))
```

`spl` is a list that contains a 1-row data frame for each row in `inDF`.

Next, you'll want to apply a function to transform the split up data into the final format you need. Here, I'll use the `lapply` function to transform the 1-row data frames, using `strsplit` to break up the variable `V3` into its appropriate parts:

```
transformed = lapply(spl, function(x) {
  data.frame(V1=x$V1, V2=x$V2, V3=strsplit(x$V3, ";")[[1]], V4=x$V4)
})
```

`tranformed` is now a list where the first element has a 3-row data frame, the third element has a 2-row data frame, and the second and fourth have 1-row data frames.

The last step is to combine this list together into `outDF`, using `do.call` with the `rbind` function. That has the same effect of calling `rbind` with all of the elements of the `transformed` list.

```
outDF = do.call(rbind, transformed)
```

This yields the desired final data frame:

```
outDF
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1.1  a ha  1  A
# 1.2  a ha  2  A
# 1.3  a ha  3  A
# 2    c hb  4  B
# 3.1  d hc  5  C
# 3.2  d hc  6  C
# 4    f hd  7  D
```

Comment: Interesting approach (+1) but it seems like doing this row-wise like this, especially with all the calls to `data.frame`, would be pretty expensive in terms of time.

Comment: when you say expensive in terms of time, do you mean CPU time?

Comment: @AnandaMahto agreed, it's a good deal slower (4 ms vs. 0.2 ms on my computer). I think split/apply/combine is the single most important paradigm I've learned while programming R, so I thought it was important to show this approach.

Comment: @CLM, I think josilber covered some of it in their last comment. When working with R, it would be helpful to know what kinds of operations on what types of objects will be slow. The code here could be sped up by replacing the anonymous function in "transformed" with something like `cbind(x[, c("V1", "V2", "V4")], V3=strsplit(x[, "V3"], ";", fixed = TRUE)[[1]], row.names = NULL)`.

Comment: @CLM, I've posted some benchmarks here: http://rpubs.com/mrdwab/so22073112 in case you're interested in looking from the performance perspective too.

Comment: thanks for your code example and for the explanations. It is short and concise indeed. What gives me a bit of pause is that for the "transformed" the columns are given manually. It works well for the example df. In real life examples, with df having >60 rows, it is difficult to use it though.

Comment: @CLM I assume you mean > 60 columns (not rows) here. Yes, another approach (such as the one by AnandaMahto) would work better if you had many columns.